# Fetch users media using the new Instagram Graph API on WordPress

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

Soo.. with the new changes that Instagram and Facebook have brought upon us, it has made it more complicated to have a module displayed on our website to just show the images from a user's feed.

**Long Story**:

Below, are the things that I have already accomplished:
- Create a Facebook page and link Instagram account (Completed)
- Create an Facebook App (Completed)
- Create a Business Manager page (Working on verifications)

I want to be able to display a users profile images depending on the username that is set in a custom field type on WordPress Admin Panel.

**Questions**:
Since we own all of our corporate IG accounts, do I have to implement Instagram/Facebook login to display user's feed items?

Is there a way to bypass this?